# Serialization is overwriting to the file

Tags: c#, serialization, overwrite, file-writing

I created a class to create the process to read and write from the user. Could someone help me why it is writing to the text file but it is overwriting itself?

```
[Serializable]
class FileReadWrite<TFile>
{
    static Stream stream;
    static IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    //Writing to text file
    public static void SerializeData(List<TFile> objectToSerialize, string filePath)
    {            
        stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);        
        formatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
        Console.WriteLine("Account Created SuccessFully!");
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: read the docs  `FileMode.Create`  
Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.

Comment: The real question is what do you want it to do, as its doing exactly what you are telling it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need FileMode.Append. As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file. This requires Append permission. FileMode.Append
>   can be used only in conjunction with FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek
>   to a position before the end of the file throws an IOException
>   exception, and any attempt to read fails and throws a
>   NotSupportedException exception.

So the solution will be:

```
stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append);
```

Or you can have an explicit check like:

```
if(!File.Exists(fileName))
{ // create a new file 
}
else //Append to a file
```

Comment: Thanks Gauravsa that was my problem the FileMode.Append :).

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear possibly this is what you want to do:
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))